# SQL ranking issue

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm attempting to do something that I assume is pretty simple but having issues getting it setup correctly (using Redshift).

```
create temporary table tmpTest (
    guid int,
    date date,
    eligible boolean
);

insert into tmpTest
values (1,'2021-01-01',TRUE),
       (1,'2021-01-02',TRUE),
       (1,'2021-01-03',FALSE),
       (1,'2021-01-04',TRUE),
       (2,'2021-01-01',TRUE),
       (2,'2021-01-02',FALSE),
       (2,'2021-01-03',TRUE),
       (2,'2021-01-04',TRUE);
```

From this table I'm hoping to produce the following in a 4th ranked column that starts at 1 for every new guid, at the latest date desc. Then the number flips for each true/false until it reaches the next guid and starts over.

| guid | date | eligible | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | TRUE | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | TRUE | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-01-03 | FALSE | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-01-04 | TRUE | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | TRUE | 3 |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 | FALSE | 2 |
| 2 | 2021-01-03 | TRUE | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-01-04 | TRUE | 1 |

The reason for this is to pull out all rows where the ranking is 1, showing me the latest records where the guid is marked TRUE consecutively by day. I've tried a dense_rank() in various configurations to no avail...

| guid | date | eligible | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-04 | TRUE | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-01-03 | TRUE | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-01-04 | TRUE | 1 |

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Although they share some ancient similarities, they are very different products.

Comment: This is Redshift database - I put both just in case since I'm not sure if there is a syntactic difference in the problem I'm trying to solve. I have encountered some things that are very different and others not so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lag()` to get the previous flag and then do a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum( case when eligible = prev_eligible then 0 else 1 end) over (
            partition by guid
            order by date
            rows between unbounded preceding and current row
           ) as ranking
from (select t.*,
             lag(eligible) over (partition by guid order by date) as prev_eleigible
      from t
     ) t
```